# replace blank values in column in csv with python

Tags: python, csv, replace

I am trying to replace blank values in a certain column (column 6 'Author' for example) with "DMD" in CSV using Python.  I am fairly new to the program, so a lot of the lingo throws me.  I have read through the CSV Python documentation but there doesn't seem to be anything that is specific to my question.  Here is what I have so far.  It doesn't run.  I get the error 'dict' object has no attribute replace.  It seems like there should be something similar to replace in the dict.  Also, I am not entirely sure my method to search the field is accurate.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import csv
inputFileName = "C:\Author.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_edited.csv"

field = ['Author']

with open(inputFileName) as infile, open(outputFileName, "w") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, field)
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        row.replace(" ","DMD")
        w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close.  You need to pass the fieldnames to the `writer` and then you can edit the `row` directly, because it's simply a dictionary.  For example:

```
with open(inputFileName, "rb") as infile, open(outputFileName, "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, r.fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        if not row["Author"].strip():
            row["Author"] = "DMD"
        w.writerow(row)
```

turns

```
a,b,c,d,e,Author,g,h
1,2,3,4,5,Smith,6,7
8,9,10,11,12,Jones,13,14
13,14,15,16,17,,18,19
```

into

```
a,b,c,d,e,Author,g,h
1,2,3,4,5,Smith,6,7
8,9,10,11,12,Jones,13,14
13,14,15,16,17,DMD,18,19
```

I like using `if not somestring.strip():` because that way it won't matter if there are no spaces, or one, or seventeen and a tab.  I also prefer `DictReader` to the standard reader because this way you don't have to remember which column `Author` is living in.

[PS: The above assumes Python 2, not 3.]

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't need the `replace` method because simple assignment does this for you:

```
for row in r:
    if row[header-6] == "":
        row[header-6] = "DMD"
    w.writerow(row)
```

Where `header-6` is the name of your sixth column

Also note that your call to `DictReader` appears to have the wrong `fields` attribute. That argument should be a list (or other sequence) containing **all** the headers of your new CSV, in order.

For your purposes, it appears to be simpler to use the vanilla reader:

```
import csv
inputFileName = "C:\Author.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_edited.csv"

with open(inputFileName) as infile, open(outputFileName, "w") as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(infile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)
    w.writerow(next(r))  # Writes the header unchanged
    for row in r:
        if row[5] == "":
            row[5] = "DMD"
        w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) to use os.path.splitest, you need to add an `import os`

(2) Dicts don't have a replace method; dicts aren't strings.  If you're trying to alter a string that's the value of a dict entry, you need to reference that dict entry by key, e.g. `row['Author']`.  If row['Author'] is a string (should be in your case), you can do a replace on that.  Sounds like you need an intro to Python dictionaries, see for example http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/ .

(3) A way to do this, that also deals with multiple spaces, no spaces etc. in the field, would look like this:

```
field = 'Author'
marker = 'DMD'
....

## longhand version
candidate = str(row[field]).strip()
if candidate:
    row[field] = candidate
else:
    row[field] = marker
```

or

```
## shorthand version
row[field] = str(row[field]).strip() and str(row[field]) or marker
```

Cheers

Comment: I think using `and/or` here is much less clear than using a ternary, i.e. `row[field] = marker if not row[field].strip() else row[field]` or something.  And the `str` is unncessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('your file', 'r+') as f2:
    txt=f2.read().replace('@','').replace("'",'').replace('"','').replace('&','')
    f2.seek(0)
    f2.write(txt)
    f2.truncate()
```

Keep it simple and replace your choice of characters.